# Rails/Heroku: how to let our users email photos to their account on our app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, attachment

I need to give users a way to send photos (or videos) to their own account on our rails 3 app, which runs on Heroku.

Since we're on Heroku (no local storage), the photo (or video) needs to get saved to our S3 account. And of course we need to be able to support a unique private address for each user so we know which account the incoming photo is for.

Any suggestions would be appreciated! I was looking at the CloudMailIn addon for Heroku, but they just give a single email address so not sure how to gove each of our users their own unique inbox address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use cloudmailin - it's perfect for exactly what you want.

You already know your users email address so if they send an email to uploads@yourcompany.com then the 'from' address identifies the user so you'll know who sent it, no need to give them a special email address each - plus you can reject it if the email is from someone you don't recognise.

Cloudmailin handles all of the email side of things and the smtp stuff and then simply does a 'post' into your application passing (to an email you specify) in the message etc you can on some of the plans even have cloudmailin put the attachments straight onto S3 for you

Comment: actually, we don't know users email addresses (we know some, but not all). tho we've been trying to find out if we use a catchall domain @my_catchall.com that forwards to our cloudmailin whether cloudmailing lets us see the 'original' destination. that would let us know which account to attached the photo to! cant find the info in their docs, no answer yet to a tech support email.

Comment: Hey, I'm one of the developers at CloudMailin. We tried to reply to your email but it seemed to bounce? With CloudMailin you can either forward your email (and you can see the original to address from the mail headers) or you can forward all your email traffic towards the domain (or a subdomain) using the custom domains feature, there's a bit more information at http://docs.cloudmailin.com/custom_domains but feel free to drop us an email and we'll make sure to reply.

Answer (score 1):

**Just an idea**

- use google apps (when you manage your own domain name, btw might be a good idea to use separate domain name for upload by email) or your own provider, as long at you have big mailboxes + catch all address support.
- catch all account i.e. uploads@uploads-company.com, that will receive mail from all users
- use *user-email-token*@uploads-company.com where user-email-token is a unique and hard to guess (user gets it by visiting his/her account page) thing that connects this email to the user in your system

**Implementation basics**

- user sends email to a special email address
- custom worker that knows how to read emails (periodically, imap/pop), extract attachments, and upload them to Amazon S3 + knows which email token belongs to which user
- use delayed_job to take care of the process (http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job)
- might use /app/tmp folder on heroku as a temporary storage before uploading to S3 (size is limited, might not work well for big videos)